# How to get anything following the domain in a url, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, hash, window.location

What is the best way to get the "anything" part after the domain part, using Javascript:

```
http://www.domain.com/anything
http://www.domain.com/#anything
http://www.domain.com/any/thing
```

For http://www.domain.com/#anything I would have to use *window.location.hash*. But for http://www.domain.com/anything I would have to use *window.location.pathname*.

I'm using:

```
window.location.href.replace(window.location.origin, "").slice(1)
```

Are there any caveats with this solution? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Caveats:*
`location.origin` is not supported by IE.
Other improvements: `.slice` is actually calling `Array.prototype.slice`. A method call that requires a prototype lookup is bound to be slower than accessing the element you need directly, escpeciallly in your case, where the `slice` method is returning an array with just 1 element anyway. So:

You could use `location.pathname`, but be weary: the standard reads:

> pathname
>   This attribute represents the path component of the Location's URI which consists of everything after the host and port up to and excluding the first question mark (?) or hash mark (#).

but I think the easiest, most X-browser way of getting what you want is actually simply doing this:

```
var queryString = location.href.split(location.host)[1];
//optionally removing the leading `/`
var queryString = location.href.split(location.host)[1].replace(/^\//,'');
```

It's very similar to what you have now, except for the fact that I'm not using `location.origin`, which, [as shown on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location) is not supported by MS's IE...
Another benefit is that I'm not calling `Array.prototype.slice`, which returns an array, and requires a prototype-lookup, which is marginally slower, too...

Answer (score 4):

`window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash`

I think this one is a little bit better. You dont have to use any functions here...

Comment: Won't get `page?some=params` <== anything after the `?` is ignored

Comment: Take a url like `http://youtube.com/watch?v=1234`, your code will return `watch` as pathname...